# Can I download a programm written in C# into nxt 2.0 brick?

Tags: nxt, lego-mindstorms

I use C# language and http://www.mindsqualls.net/ library. But I could not find how to download my program into brick. Actually, is it possible? Or I just have to control my nxt 2.0 robot via bluetooth? Are there any languages/libraries which allow to download programs into brick or it is only possible for mindstorms nxt 2.0 visual editor?

Answer (score 0):

First sentence on the MindSqualls site you linked: "MindSqualls is a .Net library for *remote* controlling your LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT or NXT 2.0 robot ... from your PC ... via a bluetooth or USB connection." So the answer to your question is: no.
If you are able to switch to Java instead, try out LejosNXJ (http://www.lejos.org/). LeJOS comes with an own firmeware, Mindstorms-drivers and a subset of Java and lets you run your programs on the brick.